# Importing reactflow v11.8.3 causes error "module parse failed: unexpected token"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-flow

Any Help here please,

Getting this error when i import reactflow

i am using react: V16.14.0, webpack 4

Error:

```
./node_modules/@reactflow/node-resizer/dist/esm/index.js 45:38
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (45:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     const getPointerPosition = useGetPointerPosition();
|     const defaultPosition = variant === ResizeControlVariant.Line ? 'right' : 'bottom-right';
>     const controlPosition = position ?? defaultPosition;
|     useEffect(() => {
|         if (!resizeControlRef.current || !id) {
```

here is the babel.config.js

```
const presets = [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
            "node": "current"
        }
    }]
];

const plugins = ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"];

const env = {
    test: {
        plugins: ["dynamic-import-node"],
    },
};

module.exports = {
    presets,
    plugins,
    env,
};
```

Tried to this code to webpack.config.js

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

but am getting same issue